# How to Instantiate ASP.net Web Service's SoapMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, mocking, asmx

I've implemented an ASP.net Web Service [`SoapExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I want to unit test it. Trouble is I have code in the [`ProcessMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.processmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that I want to test and this method expects a [`SoapMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.processmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as an argument.

Given than `SoapMessage` is an abstract class with an internal constructor and that the only two derived classes that I know ([`SoapClientMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapclientmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`SoapServerMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapservermessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) are sealed, how can I instantiate it?

Is my only option to use commercial mocking tools like [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/) or [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx)?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302177/how-to-unit-test-a-soapextension-derived-class/8330818#8330818 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302177/how-to-unit-test-a-soapextension-derived-class

Comment: And also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314672/how-to-mock-soapexception-using-moq-to-unit-test-error-handling#21349031

Comment: You stupid, stupid `SoapMessage'!!!

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with is using reflection to instantiate the sealed classes and set values in their internal fields.

Here is the code that I came up with:

```
    private SoapServerMessage CreateSoapServerMessage(
        SoapMessageStage stage,
        string action,
        SoapHeaderCollection headers)
    {
        var typ = typeof(SoapServerMessage);

        // Create an instance:
        var constructorInfo = typ.GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, new[] { typeof(SoapServerProtocol) }, null);
        var message = (SoapServerMessage)constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { CreateSoapServerProtocol(action) });

        // Set stage:
        var stageField = typ.BaseType.GetField("stage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        stageField.SetValue(message, stage);

        // Set headers:
        var headersField = typ.BaseType.GetField("headers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        headersField.SetValue(message, headers);

        return message;
    }

    private SoapServerProtocol CreateSoapServerProtocol(string action)
    {
        var typ = typeof(SoapServerProtocol);

        // Create an instance:
        var constructorInfo = typ.GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        var protocol = (SoapServerProtocol)constructorInfo.Invoke(null);

        // Set serverMethod:
        var serverMethodField = typ.GetField("serverMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        serverMethodField.SetValue(protocol, CreateSoapServerMethod(action));

        return protocol;
    }

    private SoapServerMethod CreateSoapServerMethod(string action)
    {
        var typ = typeof(SoapServerMethod);

        // Create an instance:
        var method = new SoapServerMethod();

        // Set action:
        var actionField = typ.GetField("action", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        actionField.SetValue(method, action);

        return method;
    }
```